# Displaying current value in Selection Cell GWT

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, user-interface

I'm using a CellTable to display entities' information stored in the Datastore. Data type of the parameters are String and int.

I decided to use SelectionCell to show the value of every parameter. This works perfectly when it comes to String data type, but it fails with int data type.

For instance, I have a parameter called:

```
String name;
```

Possible values for this parameter are: "Name1", "Name2" or "Name3". I have these values in the SelectionCell, so if an entity has a parameter name = "Name2", SelectionCell displays "Name2"

```
List<String> names= new ArrayList<String>();

names.add("Name1");
names.add("Name2");
names.add("Name3");

SelectionCell nameCell = new SelectionCell(names);

Column<Entity, String> nameColumn = new Column<Entity, String>(nameCell){

        @Override
        public String getValue(Entity object){
            return object.getName();
        }
    };  
cellTable.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");
```

Now, I have a parameter called:

```
int age;
```

Possible values for this parameter are: 18, 19, 20,... ,65. I have these values in the SelectionCell, but if an entity has a parameter age = 25, SelectionCell doesn't display that value, it displays 18.

```
List<String> ages= new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 18; i <= 65; i++){
    ages.add("" + i);
}

SelectionCell ageCell = new SelectionCell(ages);

Column<Entity, String> ageColumn = new Column<Entity, String>(ageCell){

        @Override
        public String getValue(Entity object){
            return "" + object.getAge();
        }
    };
cellTable.addColumn(ageColumn, "Age");
```

How can I solve that?

Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried converting the int to a string before rendering it?  Select boxes prefer to have string values.

Comment: Yes, I'm converting to String since SelectionCell only accepts List<String> values. I added the code.

Comment: Are you sure object.getAge() is returning one of the valid ages?

Comment: @sosegon - I took your code and ran it with gwt sample app, everything works perfectly. My guess is that object.getAge() returns null from some reason

Answer (score 0):

Try Creating your List of Ages before creating the dataGrid.